# How to adjust space between my images carousel?

Tags: html, css, carousel

I tried to adjust the space between my images from my carousel but I can't figure out how I can do it. I've tried many things but that doesn't work except broke my carousel

Here's my codepen : https://codepen.io/Softee/pen/MWPgbyw

```css
#slider_perso {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 32vw;
  margin: 150px auto;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  perspective: 1500px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

input[type=radio] {
  position: relative;
  top: 108%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  opacity: 0.4;
  transform: translateX(-83px);
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=radio]:checked {
  opacity: 1;
}

#slider_perso label,
#slider_perso label img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: transform 500ms ease;
}

#im1:checked~#slide1,
#im2:checked~#slide2,
#im3:checked~#slide3,
#im4:checked~#slide4,
#im5:checked~#slide5 {
  box-shadow: 0 13px 26px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 12px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0px);
}

#im1:checked~#slide2,
#im2:checked~#slide3,
#im3:checked~#slide4,
#im4:checked~#slide5,
#im5:checked~#slide1 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: translate3d(20%, 0, -100px);
}

#im1:checked~#slide3,
#im2:checked~#slide4,
#im3:checked~#slide5,
#im4:checked~#slide1,
#im5:checked~#slide2 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transform: translate3d(40%, 0, -250px);
}

#im1:checked~#slide5,
#im2:checked~#slide1,
#im3:checked~#slide2,
#im4:checked~#slide3,
#im5:checked~#slide4 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: translate3d(-20%, 0, -100px);
}

#im1:checked~#slide4,
#im2:checked~#slide5,
#im3:checked~#slide1,
#im4:checked~#slide2,
#im5:checked~#slide3 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transform: translate3d(-40%, 0, -250px);
}
```

```html
<section id="slider_perso">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="im1">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="im2" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="im3">

  <label for="im1" id="slide1"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt=""></label>
  <label for="im2" id="slide2"><img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/beautiful-sunset-over-water-tree-silhouette-nature-landscape-amazing-orange-yellow-sky-night-scene-wallpaper-birds-flying-154424473.jpg" alt=""></label>
  <label for="im3" id="slide3"><img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/spectrum-sunset-silhouette-background-trees-beautiful-color-sky-135233556.jpg" alt=""></label>
</section>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "space between my images"? you want a bigger "preview" left and right of the active image?

Comment: Hey, I'd like to keep this width of my images. By' "space between images" I mean for example, maybe having the left image a bit more on the left so we can see a bigger preview as you said :) But keep in mind I'd like to keep this shape for my images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase the spacing u need to alter the `transform3d` values. The active image has this value `transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0px);`. This value contains the 3-axis, `x, y, z`. The important value - in your case - is the first one (the x-axis). So currently the images next to the active image have the values `+/- 20%` or `+/- 40%` (negative values are on the left, positive on the right). Adapt these values and the spacing will increase.

PS: Keep in mind that the value is doubled, so 20/40, 30/60, 40/80 etc.

```css
#slider_perso {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 32vw;
  margin: 150px auto;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  perspective: 1500px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

input[type=radio] {
  position: relative;
  top: 108%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  opacity: 0.4;
  transform: translateX(-83px);
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=radio]:checked {
  opacity: 1;
}

#slider_perso label,
#slider_perso label img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: transform 500ms ease;
}

#im1:checked~#slide1,
#im2:checked~#slide2,
#im3:checked~#slide3,
#im4:checked~#slide4,
#im5:checked~#slide5 {
  box-shadow: 0 13px 26px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 12px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0px);
}

#im1:checked~#slide2,
#im2:checked~#slide3,
#im3:checked~#slide4,
#im4:checked~#slide5,
#im5:checked~#slide1 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: translate3d(30%, 0, -100px);
}

#im1:checked~#slide3,
#im2:checked~#slide4,
#im3:checked~#slide5,
#im4:checked~#slide1,
#im5:checked~#slide2 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transform: translate3d(60%, 0, -250px);
}

#im1:checked~#slide5,
#im2:checked~#slide1,
#im3:checked~#slide2,
#im4:checked~#slide3,
#im5:checked~#slide4 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: translate3d(-30%, 0, -100px);
}

#im1:checked~#slide4,
#im2:checked~#slide5,
#im3:checked~#slide1,
#im4:checked~#slide2,
#im5:checked~#slide3 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transform: translate3d(-60%, 0, -250px);
}
```

```html
<section id="slider_perso">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="im1">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="im2" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="im3">

  <label for="im1" id="slide1"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" alt=""></label>
  <label for="im2" id="slide2"><img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/beautiful-sunset-over-water-tree-silhouette-nature-landscape-amazing-orange-yellow-sky-night-scene-wallpaper-birds-flying-154424473.jpg" alt=""></label>
  <label for="im3" id="slide3"><img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/spectrum-sunset-silhouette-background-trees-beautiful-color-sky-135233556.jpg" alt=""></label>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks it's working now! Do you know how could I add arrows on the side instead of radios btw?

Comment: this carousel is based on the radio inputs. so you can't remove them. it would be possible to add a `::before` element on the inputs that renders a left arrow and an `::after` element that renders the right arrow. then you would need to stack them and hide (display: none) those which make no sense (like active image is `slide2`, arrow left can't be the arrow of `slide3`). but this will get kinda messy tbh.

Comment: No prob, I think I'll just hide the radios so I can click and that's it :) Do you know what's the best to hide them?

Comment: just add `display: none` on the `input[type=radio]` - you can delete the other stuff within that rule.